# How to hook the FluentValidation service in ASP MVC 4 or 5 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

Im using FluentValidation and doin my validation like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CourseCategory category)
    {
        var result = new CourseCategoryValidator().Validate(category);
        try
        {
            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                _uow.CourseCategory.Insert(category);
                _uow.Commit();
                FlashMessage(category.Code + " - " + category.Name + " created!", Models.FlashMessageType.Success);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "saving failed.");
        }

        return View(category);
    }
```

But its kinda messy and have to repeat in on every action that needs validation.

My question is, is there a way to hook the validation before hitting the controller? so I can just call `if(validator.IsValid)` then if validation fails, the error messages are automatically populated so I dont have to iterate over them.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do all that.

FluentValidation supports MVC's model binding.  [This document](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) has everything you need to get going:

1. Install the appropriate package via NuGet. There are different ones for each version of MVC3, MVC4 and MVC5.
2. Register FluentValidation by adding `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();` to your Global.asax file.
3. Decorate your model class so that it contains the validation for your model. You've probably done this already consider your validation is working.
4. Change your controller to:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(CourseCategory category)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           _uow.CourseCategory.Insert(category);
           _uow.Commit();
           FlashMessage(category.Code + " - " + category.Name + " created!", Models.FlashMessageType.Success);

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       else
       {
           return View(category);
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!